# Add tab programmatically with PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I use [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) for create a ViewPager inside my main layout. I want add some tabs dynamically, with different layout for every fragment. 
for example:

```
if (var == 1)
    tab.add("tab1", R.layout.fragment1);
    tab.add("tab2", R.layout.fragment2);
    tab.add("tab3", R.layout.fragment3);
else if (var == 2)
    tab.add("tab2", R.layout.fragment2);
else
    // Other tabs
```

and the fragment must receive a string parameter passed from the main activity.

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment
{
    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    private static final String ARG_TYPE = "type";
    private int position;
    private String type;

    public static fragment1 newInstance(int position, String type)
    {
        fragment1 f = new fragment1();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        b.putString(ARG_TYPE, type);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        type = getArguments().getString(ARG_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup cointainer, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View myFragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_sinonimi, cointainer, false);
        return myFragView;
    }
}
```

How i can add some tabs dynamically with parameters passed at the different fragments?